# "and this time"

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions

I have a question about punctuation.

Context: A was one successful product of our company; it was used by women. Now, we plan to create a product for men. Then, which sentence below is correct?

- our ambition is to replicate the success of A, **and this time, for** the good of men.
- our ambition is to replicate the success of A, **this time for** the good of men.

Comment: The latter one looks more natural. “And” usually connects two distinct sentences, while you want to complete the sentence in question (“our ambition … of A”)

Comment: Whether or not you include _and_, you don't need a second comma.

Comment: @KateBunting So, the sentence can include `and`?

Comment: The "success" of product A was that it sold well and thus made a profit for the company, not that it benefited women. By the same token, the company's "ambition" isn't for the good of men - it's a product ***aimed at, targeting, tailored for*** men (hopefully to make even more profit for the good of the company).

Comment: There is no useful difference in language as such and you might find more, and more useful help in Writing or somewhere dealing with Advertising or Corporate Speech…

Comment: If forced, I'd vote for the second choice 'Our ambition is to replicate the success of A, this time for the good of men' but only if forced. If the difference is worth discussing, I suggest the discussion belongs not here in ELU but somewhere like Writing, Advertising, Marketing or even Literature.

Answer (score -1):

Make the sentence more comprehensive (though it is unnecessary, it is not superfluous)

> Our ambition is to replicate the success of A, and this time, with and
> for the good of men.

Comment: Why "with" in the sentence?

Comment: "Our ambition is to replicate the success of A, and this time, with men" is one sentence. "Our ambition is to replicate the success of A, and this time, for the good of men" is another sentence. You are in essence combining these two sentences. "Our ambition is to replicate the success of A, and this time, with men and for the good of men.". English speakers typically will shorten "with men and for the good of men" to "with and for the good of men".